# Show name in place of of id on rendered as pdf

Tags: visualforce, dynamic-visualforce, pdf

```
<apex:repeat value="{!$ObjectType.Account__c.FieldSets.Page}" var="f">
  <td> <B> 
  <apex:outputText value="{!f.Label}: "/></B>
  <apex:outputText value="{!accountWrapper.account[f.fieldPath]}" rendered="{!f.type != 'reference'}"/>
  <apex:outputLink value="{! '/' + accountWrapper.account[f.fieldPath]}" rendered="{!f.type == 'reference'}">{!accountWrapper.account[f.fieldPath]}  
  </apex:outputLink>
  </td>
</apex:repeat>
```

`{!accountWrapper.account[f.fieldPath]}` shows id and I want to show name of the account.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: could you please ellaborate your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lookup fields in code always keep just Id of objects.
What you need to do is go ower relationship and get field "Name" from Parent Object.

```
accountWrapper.accountId.Name
```

I am just guessing because I can't know your wrapper class..

But basicly When you have custom object B_*c and its parent A*_c to get A name you have to:

```
B.A__r.Name
```

Comment: yes I just want the same description how to convert object__c to object__r.Name and get the details for the same

Comment: You don't convert anything, this is specific for objects database in Salesforce you just have to get this in your query and then you can use it in wrapper class or in visualforce page. There is always authomaticly created relation betwen objects when you create lookup field. You can check this relation name in lookup field. Standard objects have little bit confusing relations names, but usualu fir standart objects it is field name + "Id" eg (AcountId)